# What is $mass \cdot jerk$, or yank?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, momentum, jerk

So if Momentum is $m \cdot v$, Force is $m \cdot a$, and Jerk is $\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta t}$ what is $m \cdot j$?  I've read that the name for this is *yank*, but I'm curious as to what it is conceptually.  Can anyone explain this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the rate of change of force with respect to time.

Comment: assuming mass is constant

Comment: @Ariana why would we need to assume mass as constant, F = ma therefore dF = d(ma) = a×dm + m×da, i think, mass needs not to be constant

Comment: $F=\frac{dp}{dt}=ma+v\frac{dm}{dt}$, $\frac{dF}{dt}=mj+2a\frac{dm}{dt}+v\frac{d^2m}{dt^2}$